# Relation between a dynamically created gameobject, and data (as class instance)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The title may be obscure; but didn't find a better way to explain it.

This is the scenario: I create at runtime a list of instances of class "dog". Each dog instance has a name and few parameters (abstract example to simplify the question).

Now, when the application run, I have a prefab which is basically a panel, with a button that act like a cell in a standard iOS control. When the prefab is loaded in the scene, it create cells, for each entry in the list of dog instances, so each cell show the name and a parameter from that instance.

So far no problems, but now I would like to click on the cell to get the related data from that class. To accomplish this, is there a simple way in Unity to do so, or do I have to add to the cell prefab, a variable of type "dog", so when I loop through the list of "dog" instances, I assign each instance to each cell?

I did some search to see if there was some standard way to associate data to a UI control; like you would do with a data source in a control for another visual language, but didn't find much related to Unity.

Any suggestion is appreciated; should I use the method described or there is a better way?

Comment: note that you'll have to become expert in the `Layout` options of UI.  don't forget the trick of making one that is "in place" already, all set up, and merely duplicating it in code. rather than trying to build it and the parents absolutely from scratch in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your panel containing the dog data should be buttons so you can interact.

Let's consider you create a collection of Dog, you would create a collection of button at the same time:

```
void PopulatePanel(IEnumerable<Dog> dogs){
    foreach (Dog dog in dogs){
        // Unity requires that the object is stored in a local reference
        // Otherwise, all buttons will link to last item
        Dog tempDog = dog;
        GameObject button = (GameObject) Instantiate(buttonPrefab);
        // Name button with dog name
        button.name = tempDog.Name;   
        // Get the Button component on the new button object
        Button btn = button.GetComponent<Button>();  
        // On press of that newly created button, call the following method
        btn.onClick.AddListener(()=> 
        { Debug.Log(tempDog.Name+ " "+ tempDog.Race); });
        //Different way passing a dog instance
        btn.onClick.AddListener(()=> { UseDog(tempDog); });
    }
}
void UseDog(Dog dog){
    // Do stuff with dog object
}
```

Make sure you unregister the listener when you destroy the dog or the button. Actually, Unity does not throw exception when calling a dead object, instead it keeps it alive (??!!) and somehow creates memory leaks. So make sure you get rid of all manually. This may require more code.

The code assumes you have a button prefab for Instantiate. If you are creating the buttons via editor, then best is to have them in a collection that you iterate in the loop and skip the instantiate line.

EDIT: When you iterate through the dog collection, you create a new button, with a Button component, the onClick method receives a new method that is created (lambda expression), this method gets the tempDog assigned to it. So you created a relation between the current button, the current dog via that method. The two AddListener that I show do the same job, the second one may be more appropriate as you can debug the method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do create the collection of buttons at runtime, but not at the same time of the list of dog instances. the list exist already; then I press a button on the UI and the click call the load method to create the panel prefab, and in it, I create an instance of the cell prefab, looping through the list of dogs instance; so the cell can have a name.  What I am not clear is the addlistener that you mention: does it create automatically a reference to the dog element that I am reading at that point, right? Without me creating a reference on the prefab?

Comment: The AddListener create a link between the button component and an object. Then when you press the button, it will call the method that was created in the loop, that method is bind to the object that was passed to it.  I will update the answer with the bit you provide in the comment. Maybe that'll be closer to what you need.

Comment: I see, so it is a way to add a reference dynamically; never thought of that...trying it now. BTW the code where you do the AddListener, has an open curved brace that never get closed: btn.onClick.AddListener(()=> { UseDog(dog); }

Comment: Yep, fixed that last typo. So yep, you create some kind of relation between a dog, a button and the method is the joining part. Again, make sure you destroy that relation using RemoveListener. At least with MonoBehaviour components, Unity keeps it alive despite calling a Destroy on it.

Comment: Thanks Fafase! I did try it and for some reason, the click get recognized only for the first element that I add. every button print out the same name when I click on them. May this be related to the fact that when I instantiate the object, I do not call just "Instantiate" on a standard game object, but on my cell, which is a modified prefab? I am trying to troubleshoot this, using your code 1:1; so using plain buttons instead than my modified prefab button, to see what happens.

Comment: I tried my code above and it does work as expected. Check the part where I mentioned that the dog needs to be assigned in a temporary reference. That sounds like your issue.

Comment: Gah, indeed that's the issue....how they call it, Lambdas? I was passing the dog instance instead of creating a temp dog variable in the foreach loop. Thanks!!!!

Comment: It is not related to lambdas, more likely an internal functioning of the UnityEvent. I don't think this behaviour would happen outside Unity. Arrays and UnityEvent are not totally the same as .NET arrays and .NET events due mostly to the Serialization process between managed (C#) and non-managed (C++) code in Unity. All in all, just remember that it needs a temp ref in loops or you are up for a long night of debugging.

Comment: Indeed, you saved me hours of despair...the loop was totally fine and syntactically correct :)